# bezier drawing routine to fixed point (how to rewrite)

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I've got some primitive version of bezier curve drawing
routine, here it is

```
void DrawBezier(float ax, float ay,
            float bx, float by,
            float cx, float cy,
            float dx, float dy, unsigned color)
{
    float step = 1.0/1000.0;

    for(float t=0; t<=1; t+=step)
    {
    float u = 1.0-t;

    float a =     u*u*u;
    float b = 3.0*u*u*t;
    float c = 3.0*u*t*t;
    float d =     t*t*t;

    float x = ax*a + bx*b + cx*c + dx*d;
    float y = ay*a + by*b + cy*c + dy*d;

    SetPixel(int(x),int(y), color);

    }

}
```

This is terribly slow because of slow float->int casting,
at least on my old pentium 4 (such casting consumes 90% of time here
really, 3k beziers/second versus 30k beziers/s when setpixel is commented).

So I got an idea to rewrite it to fixed point arthimetic but I am not
much experienced with this - how to rewrite it to fixed point?
(notice that t is in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 )

EDIT:
The second part of question: how to estimate the length of bezier
curve in pixels (pixels need to be drawn)? Got no idea

Comment: FWIW, I don't know what `SetPixel` is doing, but I'm not sure I'd conclude that by commenting that line out, you're seeing the difference due to integer casting. You're also not actually doing anything with the data. Just FWIW.

Comment: Yeah, it's not just casting but also setting pixels, which will also likely hit memory. I think if you want to speed this up then adaptive step sizes would bring the best bang for the buck. For most curves you likely don't need 1000 steps.

Comment: it is becouse of casting I tell you ;-)  (can put some integer i++ j++ in place of int(x) and int(y) and it is the same) fillin the screen by setpixel takes about 10 ms - 3k beziers witk int(x), int(y) take 1000 ms without it 100 ms :O - but i am not asking about that, also the amount of pixel to calc is the second question

Comment: I think that optimizing compilers would compile the whole function as NOP if you comment that SetPixel line out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allrite I ve done it such way

```
    void DrawBezierFX( int ax, int ay,
               int bx, int by,
               int cx, int cy,
               int dx, int dy, unsigned color)
    {

    for(unsigned i=0; i<=1024; i+=1)
    {
     unsigned t = i<<5;

     unsigned u = (1024-i)<<5;

     unsigned a = ((((u*u)>>15)*u)>>15);
     unsigned b = ((((t*u)>>15)*u)>>15)*3;
     unsigned c = ((((t*t)>>15)*u)>>15)*3;
     unsigned d = ((((t*t)>>15)*t)>>15);


     int x = ax*a + bx*b + cx*c + dx*d;
     int y = ay*a + by*b + cy*c + dy*d;

     SetPixel(x>>15 ,y>>15, color);

     }

     }
```

It is 3.5 x faster becouse of no float to int conversions.
When I measured times of calculations it is about 115 ms 
versus 80 ms, (3k of it and on my old processor), so ints 
are not so much faster here (aqbout 30% only :O )

Answer (score 3):

Besides using fixed point, you can compute the forward differences of the equations, so each step is a series of additions instead of multiplications.  This is usually faster.

Reasonable explanation in [Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/forward-difference-calculation-of-bezier/184403417); shorter explanation and code [here](http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~hkankaan/Homepages/bezierfast.html)